# Form handling in a loop in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vuex

In the situation of a v-for to show many visuals in a "create" state of a form, in the case of a VueJS VueX SPA, how could I handle my form to send the data to my store ?

The exemple passed in VueX doc works well for something simple to handle like :

```html
<input :value="message" @input="updateMessage">
```

In my situation, i have loaded my store via :

```
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                visuals: state => state.myData.visuals,
            }),
```

Where my state in the store looks like :

```
state: {
        myData: {
            text: '',
            button: '',
            visuals: [{
                id: null,
                text: '',
                title: '',
                description: '',
                picture: '',
            }],
        },
    },
```

But my component needs to loop like so :

```html
        <div class="row" v-for="(visuel_lines, key) in visuals">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12" for="title-visuel">
                    Titre
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                    <input placeholder="40 caractères"
                           :value="visuals[key].text"
                           @input="updateVisuelTitle(key,$event)"
                           maxlength="40" name="carrousel-title[]"
                           type="text" value="" class="form-control no-col-input">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Should I use that :

```html
 <input placeholder="40 caractères"
                           :value="visuals[key].text"
                           @input="updateVisuelTitle(key,$event)"
                           maxlength="40"
                           type="text" value="" class="form-control no-col-input">
                </div>
```

But when I do, my store update without new data being in my visuals array.

How could I do something like that ?

Comment: What does your updateVisuelTitle function do?

Comment: Forgot to put it sorry :

`updateVisuelTitle(id, e) {
                this.$store.commit('updateVisuelTitle', id, e.target.value)
            },`

And the function called : 

`updateVisuelTitle(state, id, data) {
            state.carouselData.visuals[id].title = data
        },`

Comment: Im facing the same situation right now and still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Though same problem but I am more into looking for a solution for a two way computed property.